# Rhodes Rhomobile - Override the layout behavior for a particular view

Tags: layout, rhomobile, rhodes

I need some help with a very specific case.

I would like to override the layout behavior for a particular view.
I did found the Rhodes documentation describing what to do.
(a copy of the Rhodes documentation is pasted at bottom of this text)

I tried to use the second alternative ("call the layout method on the controller to overwrite the default layout name") but it did not worked.
I assume I might have misunderstood how to code the controller or hopefully only have a syntax error...
See more information about the application below.

Could anyone please tell me how I should do it ?
What would be the right syntax ?
Or should I use another method ?

Thanks in advance.

Louis Deschenes

### Here are some informations about the application and what I did:

- Simple application
- Build is for iPhone
- Application start in "Calculator" view
- "Calculator" view call "Control" view that call "Help" view
- App structure:

  ```
  app/
  ->  index.erb                        (Control view)  
  ->  layout.erb                       (Standard layout)  
  ->  calculatorlayout.erb             (Customize layout for Calculator view)  
  ->  calculator/  
  ----->    index.erb                  (Calculator view)  
  ----->    calculator_controller.erb  (Controller to be able to override layout)  
  ->  help/  
  ----->    index.erb                  (Help view)
  ```
- I created Calculator_controller.erb containning

  ```
  require 'rho/rhocontroller'

  require 'helpers/browser_helper'

  class CalculatorController < Rho::RhoController

  include BrowserHelper

  layout :calculatorlayout (Thats what  Rhodes doc mentionned to do)
  ```
- As I said this does not work. Please tell me the right way to do it.
- Note: As a temporily mesure I did a copy of app/calculatorlayout.erb into app/calculator/layout.erb
      This does the rendering right when the app start in "Caculator" view,
      but if I navigate to "About" view and back to "Calculator" view the rendering of the calculator is done with the standard layout.

--------Rhodes Documentation--------------------------------------------

> If you would like to override or customize layout behavior, you can
>   call the render function with the following parameters:
>
> render :action => 'index', 
>          :layout => 'mycustomlayout', :use_layout_on_ajax => false
>
> The first argument is the action you would like to render. Next is the
>   (optional) layout name, which assumes the application root as a base
>   directory. In the above example, Rhodes would look for a file called
>   “mycustomlayout.erb” in the application root directory (you also may
>   use :layout => false to disable the use of a layout template). The
>   use_layout_on_ajax argument tells Rhodes whether or not to use the
>   layout on Ajax calls (default is false).
>
> You can call the layout method on the controller to overwrite the
>   default layout name:
>
> layout :mycustomlayout
>
> This will force the render call to use mycustomlayout.erb in place of
>   the default layout file for all actions of this controller.

---

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you need to specify an action method. The `render` method of an action is what handles the `layout` property.  You cannot simply designate a layout for an entire controller.  Below is an example controller file. You would then need an `index.erb` view file to correspond to the `index` action method.

**CalculatorController.rb**

```
require 'rho/rhocontroller'
require 'helpers/browser_helper'

class CalculatorController < Rho::RhoController
    include BrowserHelper

    def index
        # perform any logic or fetch objects for the index.erb view

        render :action => :index, :layout => 'calculatorLayout'
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Rhodes has godawful documentation so its mechanics can be difficult to decipher. But I must mention that unfortunately Geoffrey is entirely wrong in this point:

> You cannot simply designate a layout for an entire controller

Actually, you *can* simply designate a layout for a controller. There are tons of ways, but specifically you can do as the docs supposedly mention, just not in the way 'ideschenes' tried. If you inspect the source code in `render.rb` you would notice that `RhoController` ***defines a setter method for this exact purpose***, which is a basic Ruby mechanic.

```
def self.layout(name)
  @layout = name
end
```

Therefore you can either use `self.layout = :layout_name` or `@layout = :layout_name` inside the controller to define a default layout. I don't know the complexities of how it may be overridden, but this technique will allow you to set a default layout for any controller. I tested it myself.

There is also a method in `RhoController` which retrieves the layout name, and you can of course override this inside your own controller if you want to customize the behavior for choosing a layout.

```
def self.get_layout_name
  @layout.nil? ? 'layout' : @layout
end
```